# Specify path to user folder in VBA for both Windows and Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am writing a tool which generates a file from Excel using VBA. The generated file is written to a folder, if it exists, in the user's Documents folder.

e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Some Folder\`

If the last folder doesn't exist, then VBA creates it. I use the following line to ensure that the location of the folder works for different Windows users distributed in the organisation:

```
If Len(Dir(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Some Folder", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Some Folder"
End If
Open Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Some Folder\" & "file.php" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close
```

My issue now though is that I also have to cater for Mac OSX users. At present I don't have access to a Mac to test, but I am assuming the above won't work.

What could could I use to point to the sub-folder in the user's documents, and how can I include code which conditionally uses either the Windows line or the Mac line?

Answer (score 9):

There is conditional compilation that allows you to compile diferent code according to the OS you are using. See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264731.aspx) for conditional compiling.

In your case you will need to enclose the specific code for Mac of Windows with:

```
#if Mac then
'here Mac only code
#else
'here Windows only code
#end if
```

I myself don't have Mac to test, but according to [this site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac007.htm) you could use the [MacScript function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/gg264812.aspx) to get the requested folder path, with the right script passed in parameter.

Comment: +1. The available constants for conditional compilation are listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/gg264614.aspx

Answer (score 9):

You have two options:

**1. Use `Application.PathSeparator`... [See the MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820973.aspx).**

Code:

```
Dim PS as String
PS = Application.PathSeparator
If Len(Dir(Environ("USERPROFILE") & PS & "Documents" & PS & "Some Folder", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir Environ("USERPROFILE") & PS & "Documents" & PS & "Some Folder"
End If
Open Environ("USERPROFILE") & PS & "Documents" & PS & "Some Folder" & PS & "file.php" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close
```

**2. Create an `IF THEN` to check for `OS`**

Code:

```
Sub SaveDoc()
    Dim wksSheet As Worksheet

    If InStr(1, Application.OperatingSystem, "Windows") > 0 Then
      'Code with Windows Path Separator
      Exit Sub

    Else
      'Code with Mac Path Separator
      Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a look when back in the office tomorrow.

Comment: @Chrismas007 `TheOS` variable is completely redundant here. You should do `InStr(1, Application.OperatingSystem, "Windows") > 0` right off the bat.

Comment: Is `Environ("USERPROFILE")` valid on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  I write on PC but have some Mac users.

```
  Set source_workbook = Application.ThisWorkbook
  source_wkbk_path = source_workbook.Path

  If Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then
    current_path = source_wkbk_path & "/" & current_date & " Workbooks" & "/"
  Else
    current_path = source_wkbk_path & "\" & current_date & " Workbooks" & "\"
  End If

  If Len(Dir(current_path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir current_path
  End If
```