# Code to open files with wildcards runs on Windows but not on a Mac system

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This code works when I run it on a Windows computer. On a Mac I get:

> Run-time error: '1004' Sorry we couldn't find file.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

I confirm that the file 'file.xlsx' is available. Is there a way to modify my code to work on both Windows and Mac?

```vb
Sub CollectXLSXData()
' To loop through all .xslx files in a system specified folder and perform a set task on them

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MergeFileNames As String
Dim MergeFile As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim Data As Worksheet

Set Data= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path

MergeFileNames = Dir("*.xlsx")

Do Until MergeFileNames = ""

    Set MergeFile = Workbooks.Open(MergeFileNames)

    For Each ws In MergeFile.Worksheets

        Set SourceRange = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        SourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count - 1).Copy _
          Data.Cells(MTIData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Next ws

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    MergeFile.Close

    MergeFileNames = Dir

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you would read the documentation.  Wild cards `*` do not work on Mac. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131131/specify-path-to-user-folder-in-vba-for-both-windows-and-mac for a way to test which is being used and then use the correct terminology in `Dir` for each case.

Comment: @ScottCraner, thanks for the references. I will refer to them and test them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not have to deal with wild cards incompatibility with the MAC system, I went ahead and referred the code to grab data from all the files saved in a specific folder. The folder can contain any excel file format. Now my code runs in both Windows and MAC environments with no issues.

```
Sub CollectFiles()
' To loop through all files in a system specified folder and copy to a master file/sheet

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Files As String
Dim MergeFile As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim Data As Worksheet

Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/xFiles/"
    Files = Dir(FolderPath)

Do Until Files = ""

    Set MergeFile = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Files)

        For Each ws In MergeFile.Worksheets
        
            Set SourceRange = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    SourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count - 1).Copy _
                        Data.Cells(Data.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            Next ws
            
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    MergeFile.Close

    Files = Dir

    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```